# Union three tables and show where data came from

Tags: sql, union

have no idea how to solve following:

There are three tables each with a column of names, for example

- Table 1 - column name 'Name' - values 'A', 'B' and 'C'
- Table 2 - column name 'Name' - values 'A' and 'B'
- Table 3 - column nane 'Name' - values 'A' and 'C'

The goal is to UNION the tables - each value of the three tables should be shown only one time. In addition there should be three new "virtual columns" showing in which table the value is included('1' when value is included, '0' if not). So the result should look like this:

```
Value | Table1 | Table2 | Table3
--------------------------------
  A   |    1   |    1   |    1
  B   |    1   |    1   |    0
  C   |    1   |    0   |    1
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select Name, max(Table1) as Table1, max(Table2) as Table2, max(Table3) as Table3
from (select Name, 1 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 0 as Table3
      from table1
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 1 as Table2, 0 as Table3
      from table2
      union all
      select Name, 0 as Table1, 0 as Table2, 1 as Table3
      from table3
     ) t
group by Name;
```

You might want to use `sum()` instead of `max()` to get the number of times the value occurs in each table.

Comment: Thx, for the solution - works perfect.
I have an additional question. What must be changed in select statement when the result table should contain in addition one more column which exisits only in one table?

Comment: @SvenMüller . . . You would add that column to each part of the `union all`.  For the tables where it doesn't exist, it would have the value of `NULL`.

Comment: Doesn't work;-(
I add the new column in all three tables. Only in one table the column has values.
Now the result is:
Value|Table1|Table2|Table3|NewColumn
A|1|0|0|Test
A|0|0|1|Test

Comment: @SvenMüller . . . Perhaps you should ask another question and put the query you are attempting -- along with desired results and sample data -- into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt (**update:** works f.e. in SQL-Server 2005 and upwards due to the *CTE*):

```
With names AS
(
   SELECT Name, Source = 'T1'
   FROM dbo.Table1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Name, Source = 'T2'
   FROM dbo.Table2

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Name, Source = 'T3'
   FROM dbo.Table3
)
SELECT n.Name, 
       Table1 = CASE WHEN EXISTS
               (SELECT 1 FROM names n2 
                WHERE Source = 'T1' AND n2.Name=n.Name)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       Table2 = CASE WHEN EXISTS
               (SELECT 1 FROM names n2 
                WHERE Source = 'T2' AND n2.Name=n.Name)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       Table3 = CASE WHEN EXISTS
               (SELECT 1 FROM names n2 
                WHERE Source = 'T3' AND n2.Name=n.Name)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM names n
GROUP BY n.Name
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f569/2/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your db supports full joins you can try the query below.

```
select
  coalesce(t1.Name,t2.Name,t3.Name) myValue,
  (case when max(t1.Name) is not null then 1 else 0 end) c1,
  (case when max(t2.Name) is not null then 1 else 0 end) c2,
  (case when max(t3.Name) is not null then 1 else 0 end) c3
from
  Table1 t1 
  full join Table2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name
  full join Table3 t3 on t1.Name = t3.Name
group by coalesce(t1.Name,t2.Name,t3.Name)
```

If you know that a value will not appear more than once in each table, you can remove the `group by` and `max` parts.